# Create new Developer Profile on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I'm asking this question here because the android forums are awful, I add a post but it doesn't show up anywhere in the forum and know one ever get back to me anyway!

I have recently been doing a lot with android development uploading a lot of applications to the Google play store. So I have one email account that has many different developer profiles on it. The way I've been adding new developer profiles (Used for different clients) is in the top right corner of the developer console, I could swap between the profiles, but also add new ones. I've come to add a new one today and I now don't have that option.

At the moment I have 3 Developer profiles on this Gmail account. My questions are:

1. Is there a limit on how many dev profiles you can have on each Gmail account?
2. Has the process changed to add new dev profiles to a Gmail account as it was only the other day that I added a new one to this email account?

Any info on this would be gladly appreciated. Thanks